# jquery using to level of (this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want get input value from first `li` clicked not from `.span-plus`

I don't know how to use `$(this)`.

```
$(".sub_services li").click(function(event) {           

$qty_buttons = "";

$(this).find(".span-plus").click(function(event){
    val = parseInt($(this).find("input.secvice_line_qty").val() + 1);
    $(this).find("input.secvice_line_qty").val(val);
    $qty_buttons = "clicked";
});
if($(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").is(':checked') && $qty_buttons !=    "clicked"){
   $(this).removeClass('selected');
   $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', false);
   $(this).find("input.secvice_line_qty").val(0);
   $(this).find("input.secvice_line_qty").prop('disabled', true);
}
 else if($qty_buttons != "clicked"){
   $(this).find("input.secvice_line_qty").prop('disabled', false);
   $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', true);
   $(this).addClass('selected');
}
});
```

Comment: Could you add your html so we can see the context?

Comment: thank you i find The solution

Answer (score 0):

$(this).parent().find("input.secvice_line_qty").val(val);

i found the answer